# moment.unix() not giving correct value for timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following timestamp `1447862653771` which I want to format.

www.epochconverter.com converts it successfully to `GMT: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 16:04:13 GMT`

I am using `moment.js` and it is not formatting date correctly.

moment.unix('1447862653771') is giving Tue Dec 10 47850 09:29:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

```js
$("body").append($("<p>").text(moment.unix('1447862653771')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/1.7.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1447862653771` is in milliseconds, not seconds. Divide by 1000 first. Note that the year is `47850`!

```
moment.unix(1447862653771 / 1000);
```

or

```
moment.unix((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

Also, there is no need to pass the timestamp as a string.

Comment: You mean 'milliseconds'

Comment: It seems that I do :p micro would be 10^-6

Answer (score 1):

The `moment.unix` function expects values in terms of whole seconds.  Since your value contains milliseconds, you should just pass it in to the `moment` function, like this:

```
var m = moment(1447862653771);
```

While dividing by 1000 as suggested in the other answer may *work*, it's not ideal, as it relies on the `unix` function to then multiply by 1000 internally. The decimals are retained, so there is no loss of precision, but it involves two operations that are extraneous, and consumes a few additional bytes of source code.